bitbucket-pipeline configured to run composer update and makes pull-request
My intention is to make use of the Bitbucket Pipeline for my Laravel project by keeping the dependencies up-to-date.
What I want is a weekly job that runs composer update against my project and when php artisan test runs successfully afterwards, that it makes a pull-request.
At the moment I have this:
image: php:8.3.10
pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Composer 
            image: composer:2.7 # because of php8.2, but prefer php 8.3: tips?
            script:
              - composer update --prefer-stable --prefer-dist --no-interaction
            caches:
              - composer
        - step: &create-pr
            name: Create Pull Request
            image: node:20
            caches:
              - node
            script:
              - apt-get update
              - apt-get -y install curl jq
              - '[[ "$BITBUCKET_BRANCH" == feature/* || $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == bugfix/* ]] && export DESTINATION_BRANCH="develop" || export DESTINATION_BRANCH="master"'
              - '[[ "$BITBUCKET_BRANCH" == "develop" ]] && export CLOSE_ME=false || export CLOSE_ME=true'
              - >
                export BB_TOKEN=$(curl -s -S -f -X POST -u "${BB_AUTH_STRING}" \
                  https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
                  -d grant_type=client_credentials -d scopes="repository" | jq --raw-output '.access_token')
              - >
                export DEFAULT_REVIEWERS=$(curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/default-reviewers \
                  -s -S -f -X GET \
                  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${BB_TOKEN}" | jq '.values' | jq 'map({uuid})' )
              - >
                curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/pullrequests \
                  -s -S -f -X POST \
                  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${BB_TOKEN}" \
                  -d '{ 
                        "title": "Merge in '"${BITBUCKET_BRANCH}"'", 
                        "description": "Automated PR creation process :-)", 
                        "source": { 
                          "branch": { 
                            "name": "'"${BITBUCKET_BRANCH}"'"
                          }
                        },
                        "destination": { 
                          "branch": { 
                            "name": "'"${DESTINATION_BRANCH}"'"
                          } 
                        }, 
                        "close_source_branch": '"${CLOSE_ME}"',
                        "reviewers": '"${DEFAULT_REVIEWERS}"'
                      }'
  branches:
    '{bugfix/*,feature/*}':
      - step: *create-pr
    '{develop,release/*,hotfix/*}':
      - step: *create-pr

At this moment the code keeps running and I cannot figure out why that is. The create-pr step I found somewhere online, don't know why, but changes some small lines; so it was runnable with node:20.
Or am I doing difficult and is there a working bitbucket-pipeline around that does what I'm looking for?

you code keeps on running might be the cause of apt-get update&apt-get -y install curl jq , i dont think you need to update and curl is already avaiable in bitbcket pipelines. adjust that and try

How did you think this pipeline would work? You are updating composer in a parallel step so the one that actually makes the PR does not get the changes

@Randommm because it works like that, because of the different images used.

@nabinsademba not working, but thanks

Can you try this updated pipeline? Also, you can schedule the pipeline using this guide
I have removed the parallel step since we need to create PR once it completes the 1st step. Also, U can use php image for this pipeline you no need seprate image for composer and npm I have added that in this pipeline. This Is the one I am using for my project you can modify this as per your requirements.
image: php:8.3.10
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Composer Update Dependencies
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip zip libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libzip-dev
          - docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg
          - docker-php-ext-install gd zip unzip
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y rsync git
          - echo 'Build started updating composer dependencies'
          - if [ ! -f /usr/local/bin/composer ]; then curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer; fi
          - composer update --prefer-stable --prefer-dist --no-interaction
        caches:
          - composer
    - step: ## Add this step to your pipeline if you want to run tests
        name: Run Tests
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - php artisan test
    - step:
        name: Create Pull Request
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl software-properties-common
          - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash -
          - apt-get install -y nodejs
          - echo 'Node and NPM Versions' && node -v && npm -v
          # you can keep your existing commands here to create a pull request or modify as needed

